# Finding Equivalent representation of a molecule/crystal

Tags: crystal-structure, group-theory

Is there a website or online calculator to determine the reducible representation of a crystal/molecule using wyckoff positions without having to analyse the number of unmoved atoms/bonds for complicated structures?